# How can I pass hidden field value from view to controller ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to pass hidden field value from view to controller by doing the following

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Articles.ArticleId)
```

and also tried

```
<input type="hidden" id="ArticleId" name="ArticleId" value="@Model.Articles.ArticleId" />
```

On both instances the value of ArticleId is 0 but when i use TextboxFor i can see the correct ArticleId, please help

Here it is

View

```
@model ArticlesCommentsViewModel
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Comments", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments.Comment, new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comments.Comment, new { @class = "ckeditor" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Comments.Comment, null, new { @class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

        @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Articles.ArticleId)*@
    <input type="hidden" id="ArticleId" name="ArticleId" value="@Model.Articles.ArticleId" />
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Controller

```
    // POST: Comments/Create
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CommentsViewModel comments)//, int ArticleId)
    {
        var comment = new Comments
        {
            Comment = Server.HtmlEncode(comments.Comment),
            ArticleId = comments.ArticleId,
            CommentByUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId()
        };
    }
```

Model

```
public class CommentsViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Comment is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Comment")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel

```
public class ArticlesCommentsViewModel
{
    public Articles Articles { get; set; }
    public CommentsViewModel Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `model.Articles` it's a collection?

Comment: No its not a collection

Comment: What dou mean by *On both instances the value of ArticleId is 0*?

Comment: Can you add the full working example with `TextBodFor` so that we can compare .

Comment: When i used the above code as well as an input of type hidden whose id and value is @model.Articles.ArticleId. That bit got missed out

Comment: Where the value is `0`? On **server** side or **client** side?

Comment: You could debug you code...

Comment: Client Side is 0 whereas if i used TextboxFor and display on the view then correct ArticleId is displayed which is from the server side

Comment: Are you using `form` element with POST ?
can you please post your controller code

Comment: where is your submit button ?

Comment: Sorry included it now

Comment: How the model looks like for the `View`, it's `CommentsViewModel`?

Comment: @user3543878, Post your `CommentsViewModel` structure

Comment: @Jeroen those values are from debug mode

Comment: In your view page is `ArticlesViewModel`? Or something similar

Comment: Since your view uses `Articles.ArticleId` but in your POST method your trying to access it with `comments.ArticleId` you clearly have a different model in the view. What is it? (the model in the view needs to be `CommentsViewModel` or if its a model that contains a property for `CommentsViewModel`, then you need a `BindAttribute` with a `Prefix` property)

Comment: @Stephen yes you are right, i have included ViewModel, i have ArticlesCommentsViewModel as the model

Comment: Have you validated that the generated HTML file contains what you expect? When you have such problem, it is one of the first thing to do! **And obviously, you need to ensure that the property has public read/write access in your model.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The model in the view is `ArticlesCommentsViewModel` so therefore the parameter in your POST method must match. Your use of

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Articles.ArticleId)
```

is correct, but you need to change the method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ArticlesCommentsViewModel model)
```

and the model will be correctly bound.

As a side note, your `ArticlesCommentsViewModel` should not contain data models, and instead should contain only those properties you need in the view. If typeof `Articles` contains properties with validation attributes, `ModelState` would be invalid because your not posting all properties of `Article`.

However, since `CommentsViewModel` already contains a property for `ArticleId`, then you could just use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Comments.ArticleId)
```

and in the POST method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix="Comments")]CommentsViewModel model)
```

to effectively strip the "Comments" prefix

Comment: "As a side note, your ArticlesCommentsViewModel should not contain data models, and instead should contain only those properties you need in the view. If typeof Articles contains properties with validation attributes, ModelState would be invalid because your not posting all properties of Article." Implemented this point and its working as expected, thanks Stephen

Answer (score 2):

In your controller, you need to pass the hidden value with the model,
for example, if you have a userId as a hidden value, in your Page you add:
`@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserId)`

In your model of course you would already have UserId as well. 
In your controller, you need the model as a parameter.
`public async Task<ActionResult> ControllerMethod(YourViewmodel model) { model.UserId //this should be your HiddenValue`

Answer (score 2):

Also make sure name attribute is specified on the hidden field. Element's "id" is often used on client side but "name" on server side.

```
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.selectedTraining" id="selectedTraining"
 name="selectedTraining" />
```

Comment: I think I love you. Thanks - that simple foundational bit a info was lost on me.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your model have another class called `Articles` inside `CommentsViewModel`.Change your controller function for accessing the ArticleId accordingly.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CommentsViewModel comments)//, int ArticleId)
{
    var comment = new Comments
    {
        Comment = Server.HtmlEncode(comments.Comment),
        ArticleId = comments.Articles.ArticleId,  // Since you are using model.Articles.ArticleId in view
        CommentByUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId()
    };
}
```

Comment: And you probably need to ensure that Articles object can be created and is created...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't put the `hidden` input in the form section, but out of form, so it's not send to backend. Make sure put `hidden` input inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was passing a couple of fields back and forth between controllers and views. So I made use of hidden fields in the views.
Here's part of the view. Note a controller had set "selectedTraining" and "selectedTrainingType" in the ViewBag to pass to the view. So I want these values available to pass on to a controller. On the hidden tag, the critical thing is set to the "name" attribute. "id" won't do it for you.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ComplianceDashboard"))
{

<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.selectedTraining" id="selectedTraining" name="selectedTraining" />
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.selectedTrainingType" id="selectedTrainingType" name="selectedTrainingType" />

if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Dashboard"] != null)
{
    // Show Export to Excel button only if there are search results
    <input type="submit" id="toexcel" name="btnExcel" value="Export To Excel" class="fright" />
}

<div id="mainDiv" class="table">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Columns(columns =>
```

Then back on the controller:

```
        // POST: Dashboard (Index)
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Index(string excel)
        {
            string selectedTraining, selectedTrainingType;

            selectedTraining = Request["selectedTraining"];
            selectedTrainingType = Request["selectedTrainingType"];
```

Or can put the requests as parameters to the method: public ActionResult Index(string excel, string selectedTraining, string selectedTrainingType)

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is not showing up is because any info to be "Posted"  must be part of the form and yours is not.  Declare it in a Div as a form group.

your code:

```
<div class="row">

     @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Articles.ArticleId)*@
    <input type="hidden" id="ArticleId" name="ArticleId" value="@Model.Articles.ArticleId" />
</div>
```

Change to:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="form-group">
       @*@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Articles.ArticleId)*@
       <input type="hidden" id="ArticleId" name="ArticleId" value="@Model.Articles.ArticleId" />
   </div>
</div>
```